# Mrjob in hadoop mode: Error launching job , bad input path : File does not exist

Tags: python, ubuntu, hadoop, mrjob

I'm trying to run the [Mrjob example](https://github.com/MinerKasch/HadoopWithPython/blob/master/python/MapReduce/mrjob/top_salary.py) 
 from the book Hadoop with Python on my laptop, in pseudo distributed mode.

(the file salaries.csv can be found [here](https://github.com/MinerKasch/HadoopWithPython/blob/master/resources/salaries.csv))

So I can start the namenode and the datanode:

```
start-dfs.sh
```

returns:

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/me/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-me-namenode-me-Notebook-PC.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/me/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-me-datanode-me-Notebook-PC.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/me/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-me-secondarynamenode-me-Notebook-PC.out
```

I also have no problem creating the input file structure and copying 
`salaries.csv` unto the hdfs:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/me/
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/me/input/
hdfs dfs -put /home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/salaries.csv /user/me/input/
hdfs dfs -ls /user/me/input/
```

returns:

```
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 me supergroup    1771685 2016-12-24 15:57 /user/me/input/salaries.csv
```

I also make `top_salaries.py` executable:

```
sudo chmod a+x /home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/top_salaries.py
```

lauching `top_salaries.py` in local mode also works:

```
python2 top_salaries.py -r local salaries.csv > answer.csv
```

returns:

```
No configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
Creating temp directory /tmp/top_salaries.me.20161224.195052.762894
Running step 1 of 1...
Counters: 1
    warn
        missing gross=3223
Counters: 1
    warn
        missing gross=3223
Streaming final output from /tmp/top_salaries.me.20161224.195052.762894/output...
Removing temp directory /tmp/top_salaries.me.20161224.195052.762894...
```

however, running this job on the hadoop (putting things together)  `python2 top_salaries.py -r hadoop  hdfs:///user/me/input/salaries.csv` returns:

```
No configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
Looking for hadoop binary in $PATH...
Found hadoop binary: /home/me/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop
Using Hadoop version 2.7.3
Looking for Hadoop streaming jar in /home/me/hadoop-2.7.3...
Found Hadoop streaming jar: /home/me/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar
Creating temp directory /tmp/top_salaries.me.20161224.195201.967990
Copying local files to hdfs:///user/me/tmp/mrjob/top_salaries.me.20161224.195201.967990/files/...
Running step 1 of 1...
  session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
  Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
  Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
  Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-me/mapred/staging/me553683497/.staging/job_local553683497_0001
  Error launching job , bad input path : File does not exist: /tmp/hadoop-me/mapred/staging/me553683497/.staging/job_local553683497_0001/files/mrjob.zip#mrjob.zip
  Streaming Command Failed!
Attempting to fetch counters from logs...
Can't fetch history log; missing job ID
No counters found
Scanning logs for probable cause of failure...
Can't fetch history log; missing job ID
Can't fetch task logs; missing application ID
Step 1 of 1 failed: Command '['/home/me/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop', 'jar', '/home/me/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar', '-files', 'hdfs:///user/me/tmp/mrjob/top_salaries.me.20161224.195201.967990/files/mrjob.zip#mrjob.zip,hdfs:///user/me/tmp/mrjob/top_salaries.me.20161224.195201.967990/files/setup-wrapper.sh#setup-wrapper.sh,hdfs:///user/me/tmp/mrjob/top_salaries.me.20161224.195201.967990/files/top_salaries.py#top_salaries.py', '-input', 'hdfs:///user/me/input/salaries.csv', '-output', 'hdfs:///user/me/tmp/mrjob/top_salaries.me.20161224.195201.967990/output', '-mapper', 'sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh python top_salaries.py --step-num=0 --mapper', '-combiner', 'sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh python top_salaries.py --step-num=0 --combiner', '-reducer', 'sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh python top_salaries.py --step-num=0 --reducer']' returned non-zero exit status 512
```

## Edit:

this is my core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
 <property>         
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>         
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>    
 </property>
</configuration>
```

and this is my hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
       <value>/home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
       <value>/home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

(the other xml config files, I have not edited/changed)

## Edit2:

here is the python script (same as on the github link above)

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep
import csv

cols = 'Name,JobTitle,AgencyID,Agency,HireDate,AnnualSalary,GrossPay'.split(',')

class salarymax(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        # Convert each line into a dictionary
        row = dict(zip(cols, [ a.strip() for a in csv.reader([line]).next()]))

        # Yield the salary
        yield 'salary', (float(row['AnnualSalary'][1:]), line)

        # Yield the gross pay
        try:
            yield 'gross', (float(row['GrossPay'][1:]), line)
        except ValueError:
            self.increment_counter('warn', 'missing gross', 1)

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        topten = []

        # For 'salary' and 'gross' compute the top 10
        for p in values:
            topten.append(p)
            topten.sort()
            topten = topten[-10:]

        for p in topten:
            yield key, p

    combiner = reducer

if __name__ == '__main__':
salarymax.run()
```

Comment: it can't find a file /tmp/hadoop-me/mapred/staging/me118248587/.staging/job_local118248587_0001/files/mrjob.zip#mrjob.zip   check your file copy.

Comment: xml files does not matter, I see paths starting with /tmp/hadoop-me , hdfs:///user/me, hdfs:///user/hduser, it's a bit messy.  Job can't find mrjob.zip#mrjob.zip, check how you set input files for hadoop

Comment: Ha! Good catch. But what do I do to fix this? I can see it is messy now, but where do I set these directories so it's more tidy?

Comment: use same user for hadoop, so all user names be the same. e.g. hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/me/ instead of hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hduser/  and then check new error logs

Comment: ok, I have replaced the `hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hduser/`  by `hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/me/` but somehow still get the same errors;(

Comment: add your python script code

Comment: in your logs I see  Copying local files to hdfs:///user/me/tmp/mrjob/top_salaries.me.20161224.195201.967990/files/..
- this means your python library moves files to that folder on hdfs.  In command startup I see '-files', 'hdfs:///user/me/tmp/mrjob/top_salaries.me.20161224.195201.967990/files/mrjob.zip#mrjob.zip.  These are files available to job. When hadoop fails it says:  File does not exist: /tmp/hadoop-me/mapred/staging/me553683497/.staging/job_local553683497_0001/files/mrjob.zip#mrjob.zip

Comment: first 2 paths are the same, that's good. but hadoop is for some reason looking local folder /tmp/hadoop-me/mapred/.. instead of taking hdfs input. actually there's no more  hadoop/mapred folder anywhere in logs. there's some misconfiguration and I can't find it theoretically. there are several places to check like app master logs and xml configs, it requires a bit of patience

Comment: @AdamSkywalker: just before the error, I read `Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-me/mapred/staging/me553683497/.staging/job_local553683497_0001`...isn't the cleaning up to blame for the file not being found at the next stage?

Comment: no, cleaning is the result of first error

Comment: [ Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized ] couldn't be part of the issue ?

Comment: @romainjouin: I really don't know anything about hadoop/mrjob. I'm just trying to get the example to run. FWIW, `java -version returns` `openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
`

Comment: I have the same issue, trying to run the examples from the book "Hadoop with Python"

Comment: @AlexMarandon: thanks for your comment. I have posted this as an issue (since you confirmed it) to the book's [git](https://github.com/MinerKasch/HadoopWithPython/issues/1). Let's see if we get more info...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ok](https://www.edureka.co/blog/install-hadoop-single-node-hadoop-cluster?utm_source=quora&utm_medium=content-link&utm_campaign=quora-post). You need to edit the file `core-site.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

and the file `hdfs-site.xml` as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/edureka/hadoop-2.7.3/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/edureka/hadoop-2.7.3/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

and you need to edit `hdfs-site.xml` as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/edureka/hadoop-2.7.3/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

and you need to create a `mapred-site.xml` file with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

and you need to edit `yarn-site.xml` to contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.auxservices.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Then do:

```
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
```

then do:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/me/
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/me/input/
hdfs dfs -put /home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/salaries.csv /user/me/input/
```

now doing:

```
sudo chmod a+x /home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/top_salaries.py
python2 top_salaries.py -r hadoop  hdfs:///user/me/input/salaries.csv > answer.csv
```

works.

Comment: Could you please explain the reason for this error and how it is fixed through these configs? Thanking you

Comment: Sorry this was many years ago. I don't remember. And Hadoop may have changed so much in the meantime (I wouldn't know I have not used it in years) I'm not even sure if the answer to your question would still apply today.